# Switch case with for loop for matching string

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, case

I am trying below thing but not able to succeed

I have file with below content

```
events_0-new
events_1-new
events_2-new
events_3-new
events_4-new
events_5-new
events_6-new
system-events_0-new
system-events_1-new
system-events_2-new
system-events_3-new
system-events_4-new
system-events_5-new
system-events_6-new
ylog_0-new
ylog_1-new
```

and I have below script

```
for i in `cat new.txt`
do
   case $i in
     system-events_*)
       for file in `cat new.txt | grep system-events_*`
        do
                echo "$file"  >> polo.txt
        done
        ;;
     events_*)
               for file in `cat new.txt | grep events_*`
            do
                    echo "$file" >> polo.txt
        done
        ;;
     ylog_*)
       for file in `cat new.txt | grep ylog_*`
            do
                    echo "$file"  >> polo.txt
        done
        ;;
    esac
done
```

but it prints value multiple time since I have used case here

current output

```
events_0-new
events_1-new
events_2-new
events_3-new
events_4-new
events_5-new
events_6-new
events_0-new
events_1-new
events_2-new
events_3-new
events_4-new
events_5-new
events_6-new
system-events_0-new
system-events_1-new
system-events_2-new
system-events_3-new
system-events_4-new
system-events_5-new
system-events_6-new
system-events_0-new
system-events_1-new
system-events_2-new
system-events_3-new
system-events_4-new
system-events_5-new
system-events_6-new
ylog_0-new
ylog_1-new
ylog_0-new
ylog_1-new
```

Desired output should be if case matches for events_* it should prints all the events output only once , it should not run same case for events_0-new then events_1-new and so on for events_2-new till the end.

This is what I want if case matches for events_* then it should print like below  not seven times
events_0-new
events_1-new
events_2-new
events_3-new
events_4-new
events_5-new
events_6-new

Actually I want to use those as environment varibale in curl command to insert data belongs to that string only

Example:

```
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:9200/$file' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d events.json
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:9200/$file' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d ylog.json
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:9200/$file' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d system-events.json
```

here $file should be fetched from new.txt as events_0 ...events_6 so on for other strings also.

May be I lacking somewhere to get this done or not aware of simplest way to do this.

Can you someone help to how I can only prints once if the case is matched it should run once as a case it should no repeat those  for other string with same case.

Please guide.

Regards,
SAM

Comment: Why do you have nested `for` loops? You loop over the whole file and then loop again over the file for each element. Get rid of those inner `for` loops.

Comment: @Philippos  I used for loop to filter the data, actually what I want if case matches it should run command for all the strings which contains that string and other alphanumeric characters i.e events_0  to events_6 only once, not sure how I can achieve that in case and for loop.

Comment: "but it prints value multiple time since I have used case here" -- um, no, it's not because you're using `case`, but because you're explicitly grepping through the whole file for every matching word. I don't really see what the `case` is supposed to do anyway, since you could just run `grep -e system-events_ new.txt >> polo.txt` etc. The grep would just print an empty output if it didn't match anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you just want to get the part before the first `_` in the string read from `new.txt` and use that in a call with `curl`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

headers=( -H 'Content-Type: application/json' )
baseurl='http://localhost:9200'

while IFS= read -r entry; do
    data=${entry%%_*}.json  # strip off all at first "_" and add ".json"

    curl -X PUT "${headers[@]}" -d "$data" "$baseurl/$entry"
done <new.txt
```

If you need to filter out the three specific types of line from the file before processing it:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

headers=( -H 'Content-Type: application/json' )
baseurl='http://localhost:9200'

grep -e '^events__' -e '^system-events_' -e '^ylog_' new.txt |
while IFS= read -r entry; do
    data=${entry%%_*}.json  # strip off all at first "_" and add ".json"

    curl -X PUT "${headers[@]}" -d "$data" "$baseurl/$entry"
done
```

Comment: Kusalananda, 
what I am trying here is if it find events then it should run particular command that can able to fetch events_0 as variable, i.e. 
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:9200/$file  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d events.json  
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:9200/$file  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d ylog.json 
( it will pick all strings with $file ) I have files that should insert to matching string via curl so it wont insert ylog.json in other apart from ylog  
I apologize if my main question was not clear,

Comment: @Samurai See update

Comment: Thank you Kusalananda, it worked for me, I have used some other way instead of storing in file I am passing it as variable, thanks once again for your time and support